# Difference between recursive and iterative dns lookup

Tags: sockets, dns

I am making a resolver and a nameserver program with out using dns libraries(such as netdb.h) by directly sending a dns message. but i have few problems. As far as i find out when we send a recursive request, the nameserver queried finds out the Records for us. Does the queries used by nameserver to query other servers, are similar to iterative queries? at least these images suggest this.

I am also confused if a client can do a iterative query or only a nameserver can do iterative queries?

Recursive dns lookup:

[image: Recursive dns lookup]

Iterative dns lookup:
[image: Iterative dns lookup]

Comment: isn't your first case an iterative, or at least `hybrid` DNS scheme? Wouldn't a purely recursive scheme follow such path: computer -> localDNS server -> Root -> .com -> contoso.com, then contoso.com would return ip all the way back?

Answer (score 6):

Any DNS client (or "resolver") *may* perform iterative queries.

By definition, though, a resolver that does perform iterative queries is a *recursive* resolver, and not a *stub* resolver.

Stub resolvers are usually implemented as *libraries*, linked directly into your executable.

However it is also possible to build a complete recursive resolver as a standalone library.  `libunbound` is a particularly good example.

Answer (score 5):

A client can certainly do iterative queries on its own without needing to consult a recursive resolver but there are many reasons not to do that:

- simplify the complexity of the software that needs to exist in the stub resolver libraries (e.g. libresolv or built into libc) on every host
- delegate iterative querying to a server in an ISP network or nearer to a "backbone" which will have a better Internet connection (most importantly, lower delay) and can complete the iterative query faster.
- aggregate the DNS queries of many end users onto a small number of caching resolvers. Most of the time the resolvers won't have to do the full iterative query: they will have some or all of the results already cached.
- reduce the number of places where the "hints" file (a list of root nameservers and their IP addresses), which is necessary to bootstrap a recursive resolver, has to be deployed.

DNSSEC throws a wrench in that: with DNSSEC, the end user must perform the full iterative query if it wants to certify the result. It is yet to be seen how the large scale deployment of DNSSEC-enabled resolvers will happen.

Comment: Good explanation, though DNSSEC part is absolutelly wrong. DNSSEC resolution process is exactly same as without DNSSEC.

Comment: To validate a DNSSEC result, you must follow the chain of trust all the way to the root (or to another trusted anchor). In order to do this, you will end up iteratively performing almost the same queries as the iterative resolution process requires in the first place.

Comment: Without DNSSEC you follow chain of delegation, with DNSSEC you follow chain of delegation **and** chain of trust, but it is _essentialy the same chain_. DNSSEC only adds extra information to the same process.

Comment: We're saying the same thing ("essentially the same chain"). I'm just adding that a validating stub resolver can't trust some random external (possibly the ISP's) DNS server to perform the validation so it has to do it all itself. [I asked a related question about how this would scale](https://lists.dns-oarc.net/pipermail/dns-operations/2011-February/006751.html) a little while ago.

Comment: Hmm, good points (1. it never occurred to me that only the one who follows the complete chain knows if it can be trusted. 2. it never occurred to me that recursive resolver is actually some not-very-trusted 3rd party like ISP.) Recently, every time I think of someone as being ignorant I end up being ignorant myself. :) Thanks !

Comment: Yet, end user can sent all those DNSSEC queries to his (ISP) recursive resolver. This will benefit from caching and end user will talk to one server only.

Comment: A validating stub talking to a forwarder needs to send queries with `CD = 1` to ensure that it gets the chain without it being pre-validated by the recursive server.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for that info. I didn't know about the CD flag.

Answer (score 3):

a recursive query:- the DNS server might send query other DNS server's in the internet on your behalf, for the answer.As proxy server sends the query to the main server for the answer.

In an iterative query, the name server, will not go and fetch the complete answer for your query, but will give back a referral to other DNS server's, which might have the answer.
it the proxy server gives you the answer unless it gives to search in other servers